# Basic logging large volumes of entries

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, log4j

I am trying to understand logging with Log4j and one of my current explorations is writing a large amount of data entries (100k) into a log file. I am currently using Log4j 1.2.17 for simplicity and NetBeans 8.1. My log4j.properties file is

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R 
# This is use for debuging mode
log4j.logger.testlogging=DEBUG

#### Appender writes to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#### Appender writes to a file
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%nenter code here
```

And my actual program is

```
package log4j;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Log4j {
//initializing the logger
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4j.class.getName());
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int testnum = 100000;
      for (int i = 0; i<testnum ; i++) {
          log.debug("This is a test and the current value is " + i);            
      }
  }    
}
```

When I view my examples.log file that is created after running this program I see that not all the entries are getting populated like I see in the console. I see it fluctuate between maybe starting at 6962 to 14752 to even 99775. Is there a limit to the memory a file can output? How do I make it so all 100k entries are written to the log file?

Answer (score 1):

By default [`org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#maxFileSize) has a default size limit equals to `10Mb`. You can increase it using

```
log4j.appender.R.maxFileSize=<number_of_bytes_you_need>
```

Or you may choose another appender implementation. You may find more info in official [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

*NOTE*

At the moment log4j `1.x` version is obsolete. I'd suggest you to use log4j [`2.x`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html)

Comment: I tried making the size 1GB to hopefully account for everything, but it's still not grabbing everything even after it goes up to 36KB. Anyway I know the 1.x version is retired, but I couldn't get 2.x working on my workspace so that's why I rollbacked.